# How to interpreter file into date and json?

Tags: import, character-encoding, json-format

I have [DateAndJson.txt](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/DateAndJson.txt) and want to analyse it.

```
data = Import["http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/DateAndJson.txt", "List", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"];
date = DateObject /@ data[[;; ;; 2]]
jsondata = data[[2 ;; ;; 2]];
```

Using this I got error.

```
ImportString[#, "JSON"] & /@ jsondata
```

I try to only handle one json object into `Mathematica`:

```
Import["http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/SmallJson.txt", "JSON", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]
(*got the right json but characters display are wrong*)
```

So how to interpreter the [DateAndJson.txt](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/DateAndJson.txt) that make it can be analyse in `Mathematica`?

Comment: You need this `ImportString[
 Import[LocalAddress, CharacterEncoding -> "CP936"], "RawJSON"]` or this `ExportString[Import[LocalAddress,CharacterEncoding->"CP936"],"RawJSON"]`

Comment: @yode: I think the trick is to use `"RawJSON"` instead of `"JSON"`. The `ImportString` then also works when `Import` uses `CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"`. I think UTF-8 the prefered encoding for JSON and thus if in doubt makes more sense. I don't see an indication that the data is not UTF-8 encoded but I honestly don't know any of the chinese...

Comment: @yode Thank you!     It can works now!